# Office Communicator 2007 - cannot save conversation history

Tags: sccm, microsoft-office, ms-office-communicator

I'm deploying Windows 7 Enterprise via WDS with SCCM, for around 6000 desktops/laptops.
My task sequence installs many standard applications (flash, adobe acrobat reader etc...), as well as Office 2010 Professional Plus and Office Communicator 2007 (not R2).

The problem is the following on ALL computers which receive the task sequence:

1. once the installation is done,I
   login    as a user, the Communicator
   client doesn't save conversations to
   Outlook(folder "Conversation
   History")
2. going    into "Tools>Options", I can
   see the      "Personal Information
   Manager"       section is grayed
   out...which       explains why
   conversations cannot be saved.

The workaround I found is to "repair"  Office 2010 from "Add/Remove Programs"...but that won't cut it for the size of the OS deployement I'm planning!

Any insights on how Communicator 2007 talks to Outlook 2010? Microsoft just suggest to open a case with them :-(
I'm pretty sure some application being installed in my task sequence "breaks" the communicaton between outlook and communicator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Microsoft Access 2003 at the end of the task sequence was causing this.
It seems Office 2003 apps could install an older version of MAPI.

Just install in this order:
Office 2003 apps
Office 2010 apps
Communicator 2007 client

Comment: Microsoft CSS gave me offficial explanation http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2121447